# Binding callback function in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I got an external js file loaded to my Angular project and one of the function is a callback function which I have assigned to one of my functions `fnBarcodeScanned(scan)`.

Everything works correctly as I'm getting alert with correctly scanned barcode but next line doesn't assign a barcode to my local variable `this.scanData`.

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
 scanData: string;

 ngOnInit() {
 }

 fnScanEnable() {
    EB.Barcode.enable({ allDecoders: true }, this.fnBarcodeScanned);
    this.scanData = "enabled: press HW trigger to capture.";
 }

 fnBarcodeScanned(scan) {
   alert(scan.data);
   this.scanData = "barcode: " + scan.data;
 }

  fnScanDisable() {
   EB.Barcode.disable();
   this.scanData = "disabled: press 'enable' to scan.";
 }
}
```

How can I bind `fnBarcodeScanned(scan)` function? As it seems to me it lost binding with the component when it was passed to callback.

Answer (score 3):

You can either use `bind()` or `arrow function`

Using `bind()`:

```
fnScanEnable() {
    EB.Barcode.enable({ allDecoders: true }, this.fnBarcodeScanned.bind(this));
    this.scanData = "enabled: press HW trigger to capture.";
 }
```

Using `arrow function`:

```
fnBarcodeScanned = (scan) => {
   alert(scan.data);
   this.scanData = "barcode: " + scan.data;
 }
```

Comment: Could you try converting `fnScanEnable()` to arrow function too?

Comment: still no change

Comment: Then I don't know what else to do. Can you create a project at https://stackblitz.com so that I can help you further?

Comment: That is not possible as external js file only works when on handheld device. The functions works ok when I dont use angular but simple in <script></script>.  But I want to integrate this with angular app.

Comment: Maybe there is other way I could pass data from this function to component?

Comment: `NgZone` may be what you are looking for: https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone You can run functions outside Angular zone